# How do I set environment variable completion in a bash shell on mac

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables, tab-completion

In a bash shell on linux, if I type:

```
echo $DISP
```

and hit tab, it completes to:

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

It doesn't work in bash on OSX 10.5, and I'm using the same .bashrc

Is there a shell option or setting I can use to set this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may need to install bash_completion from darwin ports (http://bash-completion.darwinports.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if its what you want, but how about [this](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion)?